# UML creating Use case Diagrams (noob)

Tags: uml, case, use-case

Hi im not used to UML but i have to create a Use case diagram for a system.
Id Appreciate(HELP!) if some one could make an example of a use case Any of the information i provide. the system rums on windows mobile phone 7

Mobile Location based GPS

User creates account,

User Creates Profile(identy) on the account

User Chooses Region

User Chooses to partcipate, then gets Assigned A location from servers online

User gaol of Reaching loaction met, User is Assigned Points(leader board updated), If the user Fails No points Valuse of location increases.

USer Can Equip tools, User Gets new Tools if Points Goals are reached.

User Can lookup point leaderboard, See users Rank

Please wip out paint for 2-3 mins and how me how to do one of these use cases !
And does each sentance need a use case ? or is it possilbe to give a use case to each of these lines ?

THANKs!

Comment: not new just cant remeber them lol its been a couple of years, just need an example in the context of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but ask: What benefit does creating a UML use case diagram, with stick men and bubbles, give you that the simple sentences you posted do not?  I simply don't understand what the fascination with UML is all about.

[image]

Comment: Apperently its needed when i write the system design document. I dont like UML but i have to do it and its been like 2 years since i was lasted forced to looked at UML, I have to do more than this too i Have to Create Activity Diagrams etc cant remeber them either :(

Comment: I'd recommend reading Martin Fowler's "UML Distilled" - it's the best book on the subject ever, hands down.  And it's *short*.

Comment: btw what did you create the above in ?

Comment: JUDE.  It was free and quite capable, but they've split it into  community and paid editions.  I'm not sure anymore about the feature split.  It took me about five minutes.

Comment: Lemme guess - an architecture group in your organization has decided that "all UML, all the time" will benefit you writing software.  Even if you have to create the diagrams after the fact just to satisfy them and make them think that they're adding value.

Comment: Drawing the diagram after is useless and it makes developers hate UML, while in fact it's a great tool if used properly.

Comment: "great"?  I think that's going too far.  It's the thinking that's the important thing, not the tool or the UML standard.

Comment: can confirm hate :), cant confirm "great", Thanks for the tip about JUDE its been bought out by a different crowd but they have a capable free edition available :D